# Using different SMTP server in Outlook sends email with wrong address in header

Tags: authentication, smtp, pop3, microsoft-outlook-2019

I've exclusively used Linux for almost 30 years now, but my wife is on Windows 10 with Outlook 2019 and today it's brought me close to hurling her laptop out the window.

The situation: I need to set up Outlook 2019 to retrieve incoming email via POP3 from one server (this is a POP3/IMAP account only which does not come with an SMTP server) and send outgoing email via a third party (well, work) SMTP server. I've got that working (having to resort to `outlook.exe /manageprofiles` because the POP3 server does not use the email address for a login name) but, since the SMTP server is a work server, I am using `webmaster@company.com` for a login name on that SMTP server.

The problem: outgoing email does not have `mywife@herdomain.tld` in the `From:` header field but from `webmaster@company.com`.

Question: How in the name of all that's unholy do I get Outlook 2019 to send outgoing email via a third-party SMTP server that requires authentication without having it messing up the `From:` header field?

Comment: Are you sure you're seeing the From header as Outlook provided it and not as the server rewrote it?

Comment: It'd be worth asking this same question in the Outlook section of Answers.Microsoft.com
Look for answers from Diane Poremsky. That's the gold amid the chaff from the MS employees and the so-called Independent Experts (most of whom may be the former but are seldom the latter).

Comment: @user1686 I've done the same thing with the same server using various other email clients. So far Outlook is the only client from which this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can alter detailed Outlook Settings in the Mail section of Control Panel. Do NOT use the Outlook Wizard.

Open Control Panel and select Mail (Outlook) and let that open.

Select Accounts, your Account and Change.  See the 1, 2, 3 screen shot for this.

[image: First Outlook Settings]

Then you have both Send and Receive Settings for POP and SMTP and for email addresses.

If sending SMTP and email address is not the same as POP (usually interpreted as Relaying), Use the More setting to log into the SMTP server.

See the second screen shot for this.

[image: Second Outlook Settings]

I do this. I receive at my POP ISP and send via Mail.com's portable Sender.

This works and I use it all the time.